# Quartz .NET MakeDailyTrigger

Tags: quartz.net

I am using Quartz framework, got bit confused with time generation. This is a simple code which generates daily trigger @ 11:30 am. To test this out, i generated next 100 consecutive firing time using ComputeFireTimes query but time i get is wierd. May be i m missing something here.

```
        Trigger trig = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(11, 30);
        var triggerList = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trig, null, 100);
        foreach (DateTime trigger in triggerList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(trigger.ToString());
        }
```

The output i get is

8/12/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/13/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/14/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/15/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/16/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/17/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/18/2011 3:30:00 PM
8/19/2011 3:30:00 PM

The time should have been 11:30 a.m. but it is showing 3:30 pm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are UTC (GMT) times, maybe your time zone is 4 hours different
from UTC? You would need to change the display to your local time zone
by calling Console.WriteLine(trigger.ToLocalTime().ToString());